# Django: 'Couldn't reconstruct field' on subclass of `OneToOneField`

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I've made a field `Extends` with this super short declaration:

```py
class Extends(models.OneToOneField):
    def __init__(self, to, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(
            to,
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
            primary_key=True,
            **kwargs
        )
```

However, if i use this as a field in a model, say

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    user = Extends(User)
```

I get the following error, when making migrations:

```
TypeError: Couldn't reconstruct field user on app.Person: Extends.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'to'
```

I'm struggling to understand what this means. How can I fix it?

Comment: Why don't you just subclass (`class Person(models.Model)` this is exactly what Django does behind the curtains.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem is this standard practice? I did it this way because of [this django docs article](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/)

Comment: *This is most useful as the primary key of a model which “extends” another model in some way; Multi-table inheritance is implemented by adding an implicit one-to-one relation from the child model to the parent model, for example.*: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
class Extends(models.OneToOneField):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs["on_delete"] = models.CASCADE
        kwargs["primary_key"] = True
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```